# renaming tomcat http threads

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Is it possible to make Tomcat rename the threads it creates to service http requests to something meaningful compared to http-8080-4 etc.

i.e.
Instead of just naming the thread as "http-8080-4" name the thread as requested URL, followed by some counter etc. say "/xyz_app/resource_name~1" etc.

The reason I am trying to find something like this because when you look at a profiler/monitoring tool (say jvisualvm) the thread name "http-8080-4" does not give a lot of details.

Is it even possible in tomcat?

Answer (score 5):

You could try activating the [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html) in your **conf/server.xml** which offers a thread name prefix.

```xml
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="xyz_app/resource_name" 
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
```

Then change your **Connector** to use this **Executor**:

```xml
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

This does not work for all the threads but should help identify what is processing your requests.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a `Filter` that processes every request and does something like this in its `doFilter` method:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
String oldName = t.getName();
String newName = ...; // whatever you want
boolean isNameChanged = false;
try {
    t.setName(newName);
    isNameChanged = true;
} catch (SecurityException ignore) {}
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} finally {
    if (isNameChanged) {
        try {
            t.setName(oldName);
        } catch (SecurityException ignore) {}
    }
}
```